# Parameters Optimization in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to optimize three parameters (`c[2^-5,2^15]`, `sigma[2^-5,2^3]` and `zta [0.01,0.6]` and MSE as function,) in Support Vector Regression (SVR) with RBF kernel using GA in Matlab. What should I do?
i want to define a function to optimize three parameters as mentioned with " Applying Optimized Support Vector Regression Models for Prediction of Tunnel Boring Machine Performance" ARticle but with GA, i wrote svr and GA code separetly but i couldnt define a function to optimize that 3 parameters of Svr using Ga

Comment: This might be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see a summary, but where's the rest of the question? What about telling us what you tried? Where you got stuck? In other words - there's a list of requirements, but no question.